# Loading problem in Middleware in express js

Tags: express, server, routes, connection, middleware

```
const middleware = (req , res, next) => {console.log('Hello From Middleware');}

middleware();

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.send('hello world from the server');
})
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  Please use words to ask an actual question.  Tell us exactly what scenario doesn't work, what code you tried and what you observed that was not what you wanted.  The middleware shown in your code does not do anything other than output one log when you first start the server since it's not part of any routes.

Comment: Also, to get quick and accurate answers (without downvotes or closevotes), please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This will help you get faster and more accurate answers.